# How check if jQuery datepicker is empty?

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker

I have a date picker empty, but I do not know how to check if is empty (not validated or not)

Comment: You must mean the input element.

Answer (score 19):

You can check the value of the input using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), like this:

```
if($("#fieldID").val() == "") {
  alert("no date selected");
}
```

Or for inline datepickers and such as well, use [`getDate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate) which returns `null` if there's nothing selected:

```
if($("#fieldID").datepicker("getDate") === null) {
  alert("no date selected");
}
```

Comment: I tried this but not workinh.The value is "undefined" and not NULL.any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I used something like this and it worked for me.

```
if($("#fieldID").val() == undefined) {
  alert("no date selected");
}
```