# How to find if jquery datepicker entry fired the input blur event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm validating on blur event for a text input with jquery Datepicker.
Would like to validate only when the user leaves the text input.
Currently the blur event fires on every value change of the Datepicker.
How is it possible to know if the event came from the value change of the Datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you use

```
$(date-picker-selector).click(function(){
.......//Your code to validate.
})
```

instead of .blur on the text input. `.blur` will ofcourse trigger the function, even if the value did not come from datepicker.

Or set a flag,

```
var flag = "false";

$(date-picker).click(function(){
      flag = "true";
      $(input-box).focus(); //You need this only if clicking on date-picker removes focus from the text input.
});

$(input-box).blur(function(){
   if (flag=="true"){  
   validate(input) // validate the input.
   flag = "false"; //set flag to false again for newer input, thus waiting for newer input.
   }  
})
```

> *but the click event will be triggred also when the user clicks on anywere on the datepicker window not only when a date selected. I need
>   this flag set to true only if a date selected.*

Then the selected value will be empty, solution to that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109913/how-check-if-jquery-datepicker-is-empty)...

Comment: But the event will fired when date picker input is clicked, not when it loses focus

Comment: I really don't understand how this would answer OP's issue, maybe i just don't understand it. To open the datepicker dialog, you have anyway to firstly click the input, so?!

Comment: Plaese correct me if I am' wrong. setting the flag to true means the input needs to be validated. SO if the date-picker element is clicked, the flag is true, i.e. the input should be validated,(**when input box blurred**), if flag is false, no need to validate, so it should be false if date-picker not clicked. Thus he knows the value came from date picker

Comment: Ha ya, your are setting the flag on $(date-picker) not on the input, i misread this part. Maybe this could work, let OP test it.

Comment: yes and on clicking date picker, if the input get's blurred he can also use $(input-box).focus() @roasted

Comment: Thanks OP, but the click event will be triggred also when the user clicks on anywere on the datepicker window not only when a date selected. I need this flag set to true only if a date selected.

Comment: Then the selected value will be empty, solution to that is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109913/how-check-if-jquery-datepicker-is-empty

Answer (score -1):

Thanks again OP. I've figured a solution that’s integrates best to the current site code structure: 
I set the flag to "**true**" on the Datepicker [beforeShow](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow) event and on the [onClose](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose) event set it to "**false**". Also the Datepicker is not closing after selection of date by using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041311/2660776).